# Create XML File on Disk through VB.NET Code without administrative rights

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have a vb.net application which create a temp xml file in its installation root directory
to save some configurations.

but when user without administrative rights run this application got an error and file not created i think user did not have write access to hard disk.

how i can avoid this problem. i need users without administrative rights to create xml file.

Please reply me proper solution

Answer (score 0):

You can't unless you want to have your application run as administrator all the time, which will really irritate your users, not to mention making those who know a thing or two wonder what the heck else your application might be doing with that access.

Do it properly, and put the file in one of the folders specifically created for doing this sort of thing. 
`Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` if it's per machine
`Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` is it's per user.

If you are worried about it not being there, or that a user might have deleted or messed it up. Test for that. Usual trick is to have a "template" file compiled in as a resource in your application, then if something goes wrong, recreate it from that and then store it.